# In Which Position A Co-passanger should Sit On A Turning Bike

Tags: gravity, kinematics, speed

Pardon me for this very basic mechanical science question. But I just want to clear my doubt it. Whenever I sit a behind someone on a bike I get confused when the the bike has to take a sharp turn.

I have two options:

1.) Either I sit(or tilt my body) in a position so that my body remains almost vertical to the ground. This way my center of gravity won't change much, but I get a little confused because of the feeling that my body will position the collective center of gravity somewhere in the middle of the tilted bike tyres and the head of the driver which can lead the bike to fall.

2.) Or I can let my body tilt similar to the angle by which the bike is tilted to the ground. In this case I feel what if the center of gravity(of mine, the driver and the bike) gets too much away from the bike tyres which can lead us to fall.

Please clear my doubts.

Comment: Speaking as a motorcyclist, the passenger should sit as still as possible. The last thing you want in a corner is unpredictable changes in the centre of mass as the passenger lurches around.

Comment: That's still with respect to the bike, isn't it? Not still with respect to the ground. So they should keep their hips and spine roughly rigid and lean to the same angle that the bike does.